# Javascript filter method returning the original array even when returned false

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, es6-promise, array-filter

I have a filter method as follows:

```
    let newArray = Alerts[symbol].filter(async (alert: IDiscordSymbolAlert, alert_index: number) => {
        // If Price when set is greater than alert price, price has to move UP to trigger
        if (alert.price_when_set < alert.alert_price) {
            hasToGo = Change.UP;
        } 
        // If Price when set is greater than alert price, price has to move DOWN to trigger
        else if (alert.price_when_set > alert.alert_price){
            hasToGo = Change.DOWN;
        }

        /**If the hasToGo is UP and current price is greater than alert price, then ALERT USER [OR]
        // If the hasToGo is DOWN and current price is lesser than alert price, then ALERT USER **/ 
        if((hasToGo === Change.UP && (price >= alert.alert_price)) ||
        (hasToGo === Change.DOWN && (price <= alert.alert_price))) {
            /**
             * Send Notification that alert has been hit
             */
            let userToSend = await discord.users.fetch(alert.userID)
            if(!userToSend) return;
            //@ts-ignore
            userToSend.send(`> @everyone\n\n${symbol} has reached your alert price - ${alert.alert_price}`);
            // remove that alert
            guild_modified = true;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });


    // When logged here, it shows the entire array even though certain values have returned false.
    // I know they returned false because the block in which they returned false was executed and 
     //i did receive a notification which was executed in the same block.

    console.log(newArray);
```

When logged here `(console.log)`, it shows the entire array even though certain values have returned false. I know they returned false because the block in which they returned false was executed and i did receive a notification which was executed in the same block. I know this has something to do with the `async/await`, but i'm not exactly sure what. Can someone please take a look.

**updated question**

```
Alerts[symbol].forEach(async (alert: IDiscordSymbolAlert, alert_index: number) => {
        // If Price when set is greater than alert price, price has to move UP to trigger
        if (alert.price_when_set < alert.alert_price) {
            hasToGo = Change.UP;
        } 
        // If Price when set is greater than alert price, price has to move DOWN to trigger
        else if (alert.price_when_set > alert.alert_price){
            hasToGo = Change.DOWN;
        }

        /**If the hasToGo is UP and current price is greater than alert price, then ALERT USER [OR]
        // If the hasToGo is DOWN and current price is lesser than alert price, then ALERT USER **/ 
        if((hasToGo === Change.UP && (price >= alert.alert_price)) ||
        (hasToGo === Change.DOWN && (price <= alert.alert_price))) {
            /**
             * Send Notification that alert has been hit
             */
            let userToSend = await discord.users.fetch(alert.userID)
            if(!userToSend) return;
            //@ts-ignore
            userToSend.send(`> @everyone\n\n${symbol} has reached your alert price - ${alert.alert_price}`);
            // remove that alert
            Alerts![symbol].splice(alert_index, 1);
            guild_modified = true;
        }
    });

    console.log(Alerts[symbol]);
```

Since filter cannot be used in this case with `async/await`. This is me using `forEach()` loop and manually deleting the matched object in the array using `splice()`. But since the forEach itself is asynchronous and the `console.log` is acting outside the async block. It's not returning the new array, rather the unmodified one. How can i return the new array to be used outside the scope of the forEach block.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use an `async` function with `filter`. `filter` returns all elements for which the callback returns a truthy value. `async` functions always return promises, which are objects, and all non-`null` objects are truthy.

If your `filter` check needs to be `async`, your entire operation is `async` and needs to be handled as such.

Here's an off-the-cuff `async` filtering function that does the element checks in parallel. Again, like all `async` functions, it returns a *promise* of its result:

```
async function filterAsync(array, callback, thisArg = undefined) {
    const flags = await Promise.all(array.map(callback, thisArg));
    const result = [];
    for (let n = 0; n < array.length; ++n) {
        if (flags[n]) {
            result.push(array[n]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

To use that, you have to consume the promise:

```
// In an `async` function (assuming you want errors to propagate):
const newArray = await filterAsync(Alerts[symbol], element => /*...keep-or-toss logic...*/);
// ...use `newArray`...
```

or

```
// Not in an `async` function
filterAsync(Alerts[symbol], element => /*...keep-or-toss logic...*/)
.then(newArray => {
    // ...use `newArray`...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```